# (Scientific WorkPlace 6.0) Missing style for Typeset PDF preview

Tags: errors, miktex2.9, scientific-workplace

[New user of Scientific WorkPlace 6.0]

Program sends me an error when attempting to preview the PDF file.
Error-> Unable to create a PDF file.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `ragged2e.sty' not found.
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

[image]

This occurs with the provided LaTeX template (File->New Document-> LaTeX Article). Then, I click on File->TypeSet PDF preview and the error message appears.

I'm using Miktex 2.9 on Windows 10 (no TexLive).

I downloaded ragged2e.sty from the Net but no matter in which folder I copy it, the error remains.

From SWP forum support, they say that the Filename Database of Miktex must be updated. I did that but it did not solve the problem.

Any idea ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you're using miktex as the base for SWP, then use the miktex package manager to install packages, don't try to install packages manually by hand, it is a waste of time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. It worked using this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6GdlfLC1lY). I downloaded ragged2e.zip from the Net, then extracted, pasted the folder in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex and refresh the Filename Database of Miktex (Windows search 'Miktex settings (admin)'-> update database).